# In App Billing into Preference

Tags: java, android

i'm into an a Preference Activity and i would like that when the user click on a Preference start the In App Billig so i wrote this

```
    mypref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, ITEM_SKU, 10001,   
                   mPurchaseFinishedListener, "");
            return false;
        }

    });
```

but eclipse gave me an error:

```
The method launchPurchaseFlow(Activity, String, int, IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener, String) in the type IabHelper is not applicable for the arguments (new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener(){}, String, int, IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener, String)
```

how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending your onPreferenceClick as context, define `Context context = this` in your `onCreate` in the Activity and pass that as context instead.